# No search items in AN

Tags: animation-nodes

I have no search items in Animation nodes ( Shift+A, S - type item name. But list is empty)
How can I fix this?
Blender version I tryed 2.83.6 LTS and 2.9 LTS. AN version 2.1.8

Answer (score 1):

Please use [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>] instead .

### Description

1. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> shows this popup :-

   [image]

   If <kbd>f</kbd> is pressed now, you will virtually press the "**Search...**" which show nothing.
   For some unknown reasons, the button is  currently  broken.
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> shows this popup, which is what you want:-

   [image]